# Trying to do a for loop within an if statement in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have found a manual and time consuming way to write my formula to return the proper expression for each row.

```
A2&if(C2="x",$C$1,"")&if(D2="x",$D$1,"")&if(E2="x",$E$1,"")...... etc!
```

Above formula I need to simplify and expand to all columns C-AR.  This is 42 `if` statements that I would have to write by hand. I have tried to look online before consulting here.

I am working on the formula on column B:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g4Xv48KdkJnHXNmpUSchrh2GXvJ54VHnhuYnjw-Mjfk/edit?usp=sharing

I tried to make a formula.  I can do it by hand, but I am looking for a faster method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ARRAYFORMULA and CONCATENATE to compare all the columns in that row:

```
=A2&CONCATENATE(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:AR2="x",C$1:AR$1,)))
```

[image]

You can also delete all that column, and put this formula in B1 and it will cover the whole column:

```
=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(r,IF(r="","",r&CONCATENATE(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(INDEX(C:AR,ROW(r))="x",C$1:AR$1,))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following dynamic array formula-

```
=MAP(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),
LAMBDA(t,JOIN("",t,IFERROR(FILTER(C1:1,CHOOSEROWS(C:AR,ROW(t))="x"),""))))
```

[image]